# How to set selected option right after injecting innerHTML into DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a php script that generates a list of time between starting time and ending time with increments of 15min. On HTML side, I have two select dropdown for starting and ending time and I load the same php script for both select dropdown. I inject the list into innerHTML of the DOM, then I use jQuery to set the ending time to the last value in the list.

I can see in the HTML source that the last value for ending time is selected, but in the select dropdown, I only see the first value for the ending time. How do i update/refresh the select dropdown to show the actual selected value?

```
function addEmployee() {
        var num = 1;
        var fields= html("employees").innerHTML;
        num += html("employees").getElementsByTagName('a').length;
        if(num <= 14) {
            fields+="<div id=\"employee_line"+num+"\">";
            fields+="<label for=\"employeeName"+num+"\">Employee: <select name=\"employeeName"+num+"\"><?php echo $opts; ?></select></label> ";
            if(scheduler.templates.event_date(new Date(html("start_date").value)) == "07:00") {
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\">Start Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_morning; ?></select></label> ";
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\">End Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_morning; ?></select></label> ";
            } else if(scheduler.templates.event_date(new Date(html("start_date").value)) == "12:00") {
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\">Start Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_afternoon; ?></select></label> ";
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\">End Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_afternoon; ?></select></label> ";
            } else if(scheduler.templates.event_date(new Date(html("start_date").value)) == "17:00") {
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\">Start Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeStart"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_evening; ?></select></label> ";
                fields+="<label for=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\">End Time: <select name=\"employeeTimeEnd"+num+"\"><?php echo $time_evening; ?></select></label> ";
            }
            fields+="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"delete_employee("+num+")\">del</a>";
            fields+="<br /></div>";
            document.getElementById("employees").innerHTML = fields;
            $('select[name^="employeeTimeStart' + html("employees").getElementsByTagName('a').length + '"]').children('option').each(function(index, obj) {
                var date = new Date(html("start_date").value.toString("r"));
                if(scheduler.templates.event_date(date) == $(obj).val()) {
                    $(obj).attr("selected", "selected");
                }
            });
            $('select[name^="employeeTimeEnd' + html("employees").getElementsByTagName('a').length + '"]').children('option').each(function(index, obj) {
                var date = new Date(html("end_date").value.toString("r"));
                if($(obj).val() == scheduler.templates.event_date(date)) {
                    $(obj).attr("selected", "selected");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Maximum number of employees reached.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Like the 2^10 ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .prop to change the selected property.

```
$(obj).prop("selected", true);
```

Alternatively you could instead do

```
$(theselect).val(thevalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the .on

```
$("select").on("change", function(event){
alert($(this).val());
});
```